# How to get every second element/character from a string in python?

Tags: python, string, character

I've this string: *mystr = 'one two three four five six'*
and I want to get every second element from a string. So the output I want is: *'two four six'*
Because eventually I want the output to be as: 'one owt three ruof five xis' i.e; I want to reverse every second element from the string and that's why I'm fetching every second element from a string.
Can you please help me with it?!
Thank you in advance!

Don't mind but this what I was trying;

```
mystr = 'one two three four five six'
mystr.split(" ")
# print(type(mylist))
# print(len(mylist))
mylist = list(mystr)
print((mylist))
print(len(mylist))
```

Comment: `mystr.split()[1::2]`?

Comment: If your goal is to just reverse the words, you don't need to extract them, just iterate over the words after doing split

Comment: Here's a one line solution to get your final output `output = ' '.join([w[::-1] if i % 2 else w for i, w in enumerate(mystr.split())])`

Comment: `mystr` does not suddenly change its type to be a list now. When you do `mystr.split(" ")` the string is splitted and given back to you as a list. But you ignore the returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a concise and efficient solution you can use a list-builder notation to create an array where the word is reversed (`w[::-1]`) at even indices and forwards at odd indices (`w`). `enumerate(some_list)` allows you to iterate over the indices and values simultaneously. In this case, we used `mystr.split()` to split it at the spaces. At the end, all you need to do is join.

```py
mystr = 'one two three four five six'
output = ' '.join([w[::-1] if i % 2 else w for i, w in enumerate(mystr.split())])
print(output)
```

Output: `"one owt three ruof five xis"`

As an alternative solution which you may find more readable, but is less consice and less efficient, would be to iterate over a range starting from 1 with a skip of 2, and reverse each word as its index appears in the loop.

```py
mystr = 'one two three four five six'
# split the string into a list of words
words = mystr.split()
# reverse every other word in the list
for i in range(1, len(words), 2):
    words[i] = words[i][::-1]
# join the list back into a string
print(' '.join(words))
```

Output: `"one owt three ruof five xis"`